# Problems with using execvp on a constructed string

Tags: c, string, execvp

I'm trying to write a shell, and part of its construction is executing code from a user-inputted string (buffer). However, when I attempt to execvp the string with additional inputs (ae. echo a), it always screws the pooch and returns -1. I'm at a loss as to why. Here's the relevant pieces:

```
char * buffer = calloc(100, sizeof(char));
...
fgets(buffer, 100, stdin);
buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = 0; // necessary because of a newline inserted by fgets
...
cmd = strsep(&buffer, " ");
char * str = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
strcat(str, "./");
strcat(str, cmd);
strcat(str, ".out");
...
i = execvp(str, (char * *) buffer);
```

Comment: The second argument to `execvp()` must be a null-terminated array of character pointers.  For example: `char *argv[] = { "xyz.out", 0 };`. Bludgeoning the compiler into accepting your erroneous code with a cast produces the same results that any other similar threat does: the victim (the compiler) acquiesces to your request and then conspires to ensure it doesn't work out the way you intended (and it doesn't have to work very hard).  Casts are necessary sometimes; this is not one those times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `buffer` is wrong. The second argument of `execvp` is an array of pointers. With this cast, you are hidding a compiler warning, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a couple of potential problems here.

First, you're allocating space with `malloc` (meaning the contents aren't initialized), but immediately using `strcat` to write to it. Unless (by whatever change) the first character is a `'\0'`, that's going leave you with a string starting with garbage, followed by data you're trying to put there. It would also (very easily) lead to writing past the end of the buffer, giving undefined behavior.

If it were up to me, I think I'd use `sprintf` instead of `strcat`. At least what you've shown would work out to: `sprintf(str, "./%43s.out", cmd);`

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. You are passing an uninitialized string to the first strcat.
2. execvp expects an array of strings, not a single string with null-separated fields.