# memory allocation for pointers in c

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have an array as follows:

```
 char* arg[1024];
```

Now to initialize arg which I will be passing to a function I am doing the following:

```
 arg = (char**)calloc(1024,sizeof(char*));
```

However whenever I pass arg to the function. I end up getting a segmentation fault. The function is basically doing some very simple command to word parsing:

```
 void parse(char* buffer, char** arg)
 {
   while(*buffer!='\0')
   {
     *arg=buffer;
      arg++;
      while(*buffer!=' ')
      buffer++;

      while(*buffer == ' ')
      {
         *buffer = '\0';
          buffer++;
      }         

   }
 }
```

Am I doing something wrong in memory allocation? or passing pointers?

Comment: Your memory allocation and your algorithm show two *intended* (supposedly) different behaviors. Either you want to manage a list of strings, or you want to have a string of 1024 chars allocated at first. In both cases the code above is not correct anyway. Maybe you should tell us what you want to do?

Answer (score 4):

```
char* arg[1024];
```

provides a statically allocated array of 1024 `char` pointers. You do not need to allocate it dynamical again. So remove your `calloc()` line.

Besides your allocation problem there is another bug. Take a look at:

```
while(*buffer != ' ')
    buffer++;
```

What happens if `buffer = "test"`? Your `while`-loop will not find a space and continues to iterate outside `buffer`. Resulting in all kinds of undefined behavior...

To fix it you need to check for the string terminator as well:

```
while(*buffer != 0 && *buffer != ' ')
    buffer++;
```

Answer (score 1):

`char* arg[1024];`  is array of *char pointers*.

`arg = (char**)calloc(1024,sizeof(char*));` is wrong. We can't assign new allocated memory address to `arg`.

if you want to create *array of strings* then do like this: (*I think you need this*)

```
char* arg[1024];
arg[i] = (char*)calloc(1024,sizeof(char));
```

where `i` is an index.

<sub>You says `segmentation fault.` but I think you should get an compilation error for `arg = (char**)calloc(1024,sizeof(char*));`  statement. *error: incompatible types when assigning*</sub>

I also noticed errors in  `parse()`. (answered by *Veger*)
<sub>You can also use `strsep()` function for parsing you `buffer` string, here [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779872/problems-with-using-execvp-on-a-constructed-string/13780083#13780083) can be useful for this purpose.</sub>

Comment: Right, `arg = (char**)calloc(1024,sizeof(char*));` mustn't compile if `arg` is declared as in the question.

Answer (score 1):

arg is already allocated in your case. you say you need it to be 1024 elements big -- its statically allocated

=> leave the out the `char *arg[1024]` and replace it with `char **arg`