# How do I create a buffer for this in order to test if there are still arguments available?

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, buffer, sizeof

```
while (sizeof(cmds[x]) > 0){
  here:
    if (cmds[x][y] == " "){

      y++;
      goto here;
   }
    else argvector[x][y] = cmds[x][y];
  }
  x++;
  y = 0;
  goto nextCMD;
```

This is part of a larger code.  I was wondering how this can work. I think I need to use a buffer in order to use the size of call.
From looking at this, Is there a better way to go about it **?**
I am basically parsing through a command line to get augments separated by pipes `"|"`.  Then I have to parse again (this code above) to extract the actual command followed by its arguments.  Thoughts **?**

Comment: http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html

Comment: try not using gotos.. how about trying a push / pull buffer?

Comment: you can use [strsep(char **stringp, const char *delim)](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strsep.3.asp) function use for  parsing you `cmds` buffer, here [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779872/problems-with-using-execvp-on-a-constructed-string/13780083#13780083) can be useful for this purpose.

Comment: Also, `while (sizeof(cmds[x]))` is quite unlikely to ever do anything useful in C.  `sizeof` is a compile-time constant in C and is only about type information.  You are probably looking for `strlen`.